# How to scroll page indicators with carousel page while indicators width is more than carousel view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am try to develop carousel page with page indicators but I have struggle to scroll the page indicators with carousel view scrolling. In my sample page indicators width is more width then carousel view page, so it's width exceeds the carousel view page.

Due to that after scrolling some positions I am not able to show highlighted page indicators to the user because it's width exceeds carousel view page.

Comment: there is already Xamarin control Carousel view with page indicators. Is it not good enough for you?

Comment: Show some code of what you are doing.